# select dropdown displays utf-8 characters but not displaying chinese characters

Tags: cakephp, utf-8, cjk

The coding is done in cakephp.

There is a variable defined called `types` which stores an array populated from the database itself.

The site is in chinese, so the database stores utf-8 characters.

When we are trying to display the dropdown, it does not display the chinese characters
but the utf-8 characters.

If I do a `print_r` of the that variable types, it prints out the chinese characters but does not display the same in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have following in your layout.. if not then try adding it:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Hope it helps

Comment: for option value it displays the correct chinese characters but between the option tags it does not like e.g <option value="chinese characters here">displays utf-8 format</option>

Comment: are you getting the values from database..?

Comment: try using normal select tags instead of using cakephp's input tag for select, and it might solve your problem.